# Cannot have JSP page load with Jersey server

Tags: jsp, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using jersey 2.4 for my web service and cannot have the home page load the index.jsp. I made a IndexService POJO to try loading it from there too, but that doesn't work. I would like to just use the home page, instead of the having an IndexService POJO. The POJO is reached but returns this:

HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable.

My web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Dependencies pom.xml files:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

IndexService POJO:

```
@Path("/")
public class IndexService {

    @GET
    @Path("/index")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable indexPage() {
        return new Viewable("/index.jsp", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to add [JspMvcFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/jsp/JspMvcFeature.html) to the configuration of your application. Since you're using `web.xml` to configure your application (package scanning of resources and providers, setting property) you need to add the following `init-parameter`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helps me a lot

Answer (score 4):

Michal Gajdos answer is correct, but I would also to add details about the cases in which the configuration is done by extending the JAX-RS `Application` class or the Jersey `ResourceConfig` class.

Notice that from Jersey 2.x you have to explicitly register the extension Features you are going to use ([see official documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.22.1/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable)).

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        resources.add(org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature.class);
        return resources;
    }

    // ...
}
```