# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html but works for JSON

Tags: java, rest, maven, model-view-controller, jersey

The problem is that whenever I try to produce response of media type anything other than JSON, I get "MessageBodyWriter" not found error.
But the response works fine for Application_JSON outputs.
I am using several dependencies in my Maven POM so maybe MessageBodyWriter is getting overridden or maybe only for JSON its included.

Here are the pom dependencies -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl </artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

The sample Java class I am using is -

```
package com.va;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("orders")
public class OrderView{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable index() {
        return new Viewable("index");
    }

}
```

Also I have kept my index.htm file in webapp folder.
The config for web.xml is as -

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.va</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/webapp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(webapp)/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

On accessing the URL localhost:8080/myapp/orders
I get HTTP 500 error and console error as

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable.
```

Please guide me with what is the issue. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: I think you have to register the feature. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865738/cannot-have-jsp-page-load-with-jersey-server

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw the JspMvcFeature i have already registered. Its there if you check the web.xml code.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to note here you should be using servlet filters not serlvet when using jersey mvc template. Also, some of your init parameter referring to Jersey 1  and should be changed to Jersey 2 equivalent. More here [Jersey MVC Template](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html)

Updated web.xml. Give it a try.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey REST Service</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.va</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/webapp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Jersey REST Service</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```